# Black areas after rendering in Cycles - Material Issue

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, camera

my renderings are showing up like this:[image: Black area on edge of the Floor]

When i move the Camera up ore down, the black area changes also. I play around with Clipping and that did not help.
[image: Clip Start 0.1m, End 1000m]

I also checked all the faces orientated in the right way.
[image: All Faces are blue]

But when i apply another material to the Floor, the Black Areas are gone.

I used the same "beton-material" i used on the Floor, on a wall and there it shown up right.
(Beton-Image for Color channel + Beton-Image for Normal Map)
[image: nodes for material]

I am not sure, if this a Camera ore a material problem...

You can also download this project file here an have a look on it: https://we.tl/t-EAdl5p9Slk

So i really hope someone have an idea ore a tip, what else I can try!
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your "Normal Map" "Tangent Space". Try a different value and the blackness will in- or decrease. Or, maybe, if you like this: put the alpha-plaster17 as strength (Normal Map) and color to color.

[image: All "Normal" here]

Comment: Wow, thanks gilu! So easy, but so helpful. :)